# How to know the tensorflow version of a tensorflow model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I just want to know the tensorflow version of a tensorflow model ( h5 ) file .

I want to know the version number of tensorflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this be useful to you?

```
import h5py
import re

def get_tensorflow_version(h5):
    with h5py.File(h5, 'r') as f:
        metadata = f.attrs['model_config'].decode('utf-8')
        version = re.search(r'"tensorflow_version":\s*"([^"]*)', metadata)
        if version:
            return version.group(1)
        else:
            return "No Version"

print(get_tensorflow_version('xxx.h5'))
```

Replace the xxx with the file name